# uwp basic transition not working

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have a super basic UWP application.  I need to display a popup with a nice transition, but can't seem to make it work?!?  Am I doing anything wrong?  I open the popup in the code behind using `popup1.IsOpen = true`

PS: Please don't suggest me to use another control.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

        <Popup x:Name="popup1">
            <Popup.Transitions>
                <TransitionCollection>
                    <PopupThemeTransition FromHorizontalOffset="100"/>
                </TransitionCollection>
            </Popup.Transitions>

            <Border x:Name="brd1" Background="Blue" >
                <Button x:Name="btnClose" Background="White" Click="btnClose_Click"  Margin="100">test</Button>
            </Border>
        </Popup>

        <Button x:Name="btnOpen" Click="btnOpen_Click">go</Button>

    </Grid>
```

Comment: are you sure about using a popup? if you want to show a pop up that comes over the button then you're looking for a flyout.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to go about it. you can replace your events with `interactivity` and `behaviors` but since you've not used them in your sample code, I won't share that. So I've written up a code sample to get your animation working.

I've created some sample code that has `native` and `storyboard` animations:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="ShowPopup">
            <PopInThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyPopup" />
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Name="HidePopup">
            <PopOutThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyPopup" />
        </Storyboard>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Popup x:Name="MyPopup" IsOpen="True"
       HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Popup.Transitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <PopupThemeTransition />
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Popup.Transitions>
        <Grid Height="200" Width="200" Background="Red">
            <StackPanel>
                <Button Content="Hide (Native)" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="hide_native_click"/>

                <Button Content="Hide (Storyboard)" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="hide_storyboard_click"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Popup>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Show Popup (Native)" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="show_native_click"/>

        <Button Content="Show Popup (Storyboard)" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="show_storyboard_click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

and the code behind looks like below:

```
private void hide_native_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyPopup.IsOpen = false;
}

private void hide_storyboard_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    HidePopup.Begin();
}

private void show_native_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyPopup.IsOpen = true;
}

private void show_storyboard_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ShowPopup.Begin();
}
```